# Select from a set of inputs_ Legend line style_ Grid style legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, tkz-kiviat

I have a `\foreach` loop in the following macro to create a legend box for my radar chart. First, how can I make legend to be in two columns and two rows? Second, I have used the 4th input of the `\LegendBox` for the line style. But I don't know how to select a single element of the fourth array in every loop. In short, how can I make legend lines to be `{solid, dashed, dotted, dashed}` in order?
To run the following code, you need to add `tkz-kiviat.sty` file!
Thanks

[image]

```
% Add tkz-kiviat.sty file first!!!!!!!!!!
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
%%%%%Make sure to add "tkz-kiviat.sty file   !!!!!!!!!

\usepackage{tkz-kiviat} 
\newcommand{\LegendBox}[4][]{%
    \coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
    
    \foreach \col/\item [count=\hi from 0] in {#3} {
           
\draw[line width=0.5mm,color=\col,style={#4}] ([yshift=\hi*15mm]LegendBox_anchor) -- ++(1.5,0)
                                node[anchor=west][color=\col] {\item}
                                ;}
 %  \draw ([shift={(-2,-.4)}]LegendBox_anchor)rectangle([shift={(4.5,2)}]LegendBox_anchor);
  }
%%%%!!!!!!!!!!!!End of part  for Radar chart !!!!!!!%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /kiviatgrad/simplify label/.code={
        \ifx\nv\undefined\else
            \pgfmathparse{Mod(\nv,5)}
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt>0pt
                \tikzset{opacity=0}
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzKiviatDiagram[lattice style/.style={gray!50}, scale=0.2, gap=1,, lattice=15]{A,B,C,D}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,
color=red,
mark=ball,
ball color=red,
mark size=4pt,opacity=.2,
fill=red!20](5,9,6,8,4)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,
color=blue,
mark=ball,
mark size=4pt,
fill=blue!20,
opacity=.5](4,6,6,4,3)
    \tkzKiviatGrad[simplify label=10](7)  
     \LegendBox[shift={(-3cm,-1cm)}]{current bounding box.south}%
      {blue/blue decription,
       olive/blue description,
       green/green,
       red/red
       }{solid,dashed,dotted,dashed}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely other, more flexible, options, but for this specific case you could modify the `\LegendBox` macro to something like this:

```
\newcommand{\LegendBox}[4][]{%
    \coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
    
    \foreach \col/\item/\linestyle [count=\hi from 0] in {#3} {
         \draw[
           line width=0.5mm,
           color=\col,
           \linestyle,
           style={#4}
           ] ([xshift={floor(\hi/2)*18cm}, % adjust 18cm depending on label widths
               yshift={mod(\hi,2)*15mm}]LegendBox_anchor) -- ++(1.5,0)
                                node[anchor=west] {\item}
          ;
    }
}
```

In the original code the legend entries are just shifted down based on the counter `\hi`. In this version they're shifted down based on `mod(\hi, 2)`, and shifted right depending on `floor(\hi/2)`. That takes care of the grid layout.

For the linestyle, that is added in the list of colors/legend entries, so you need e.g. `blue/blue description/solid` instead of `blue/blue description` when you call `\LegendBox`. See example below

[image: Output of the code below]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
%%%%%Make sure to add "tkz-kiviat.sty file   !!!!!!!!!

\usepackage{tkz-kiviat} 
\newcommand{\LegendBox}[4][]{%
    \coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
    
    \foreach \col/\item/\linestyle [count=\hi from 0] in {#3} {
         \draw[
           line width=0.5mm,
           color=\col,
           \linestyle,
           style={#4}
           ] ([xshift={floor(\hi/2)*18cm}, % adjust 18cm depending on label widths
               yshift={mod(\hi,2)*15mm}]LegendBox_anchor) -- ++(1.5,0)
                                node[anchor=west] {\item}
          ;
    }
}
%%%%!!!!!!!!!!!!End of part  for Radar chart !!!!!!!%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
    /kiviatgrad/simplify label/.code={
        \ifx\nv\undefined\else
            \pgfmathparse{Mod(\nv,5)}
            \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt>0pt
                \tikzset{opacity=0}
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[lattice style/.style={gray!50}, scale=0.2, gap=1,, lattice=15]{A,B,C,D}

\tkzKiviatLine[thick,
  color=red,
  mark=ball,
  ball color=red,
  mark size=4pt,opacity=.2,
  fill=red!20](5,9,6,8,4)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,
  color=blue,
  mark=ball,
  mark size=4pt, 
  fill=blue!20,
  opacity=.5](4,6,6,4,3) 
\tkzKiviatGrad[simplify label=10](7)  
  
\LegendBox[shift={(-3cm,-1cm)}]{current bounding box.south}%
      % here you specify line styles as well
      {blue/blue description/solid,
       olive/olive description/dashed,
       green/green/dotted,
       red/red/dashed%
       }{} % the final argument is empty
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```